# fastboot flashing error: "Partition should be flashed in fastbootd"

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, google-pixel

I am new to Android development and trying to flash a custom ROM to my Pixel 3a. It was built through the Android Open Source Project. But I am facing the following error.

```
user@user-Predator-PH315-52:~/aosp$ fastboot flashall -w
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: b4s4-0.2-5736883
Baseband Version.....: g670-00030-191028-B-5972069
Serial Number........: 9A9AY1CEC7
--------------------------------------------
Checking product
OKAY [  0.060s]
target reported max download size of 268435456 bytes
Erase successful, but not automatically formatting.
File system type raw not supported.
Erase successful, but not automatically formatting.
File system type raw not supported.
Sending 'boot_b' (65536 KB)...
OKAY [  2.340s]
Writing 'boot_b'...
OKAY [  0.346s]
Sending 'dtbo_b' (8192 KB)...
OKAY [  0.384s]
Writing 'dtbo_b'...
OKAY [  0.095s]
Sending sparse 'system_b' 1/5 (262140 KB)...
OKAY [  9.245s]
Writing 'system_b' 1/5...
FAILED (remote: Partition should be flashed in fastbootd)
Finished. Total time: 14.348s
```

How to fix this error?

**Phone**: Pixel 3a
**Build**: 9.0.0(PD2A.190115.032, Mar 2019)

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue on my Pixel 3a XL. You need the most up-to-date version of ADB and fastboot. Grab it from Google to be sure you have the most recent, you only need the [SDK Platform-Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools). Don't have to download the whole SDK Platform.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go into fastbootd mode.

Hold power key + volume down, you will boot into recovery. Choose to enter fastboot, then run:

```
fastboot flashall -w
```